# Pan Digital Split among Two Powers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

$Given$:

$AB$, $DBCE$,$AGFPQR$ are three concatenated numbers with all distinct digits varying from zero to nine.

$AB^C$ = $DBCE$

$AB^F$ = $AGFPQR$

Deduce all the digits through logical reasoning only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters are

> A = 1, B = 8 ,C = 3,  D = 5, E = 2, F = 4, G = 2, P = 9, Q = 7, R = 6

Explanation

> A at the ten's place can't be zero. C and F being exponents can't be zero. B, E, R at the one's place can't be zero.
> So, out of G, P and Q one of them is zero.
>  Working from, $$AB^C = DBCE$$ I started with the power $3$.
> $21^3 = 9261$ is the maximum value with 4 digits. So from 21 in back, $20^3 = 8000$ is not possible so is 19. $18^3 = 5832$ seems as a possible solution.
>  Now $$18^4 = 104976$$

Comment: That’s right...

Comment: Accept after a while, so as to get other puzzlers' attention : )

Comment: Sure............